# how to validate date which can take last month and current month date in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am little bit stuck, I am new to Vuejs, and I am using vuetify as a library for making my UI part of application.

I have a scenario where I am using `v-date-picker` to select dates but I have a problem I want to select select dates from last month and current month and rest all the months in datepicker should be disabled.

Means a user can select the date only from `April` month and `May` month as `May` is our current month so how should I solve this problem ?

Here is my default code.

```html
<v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title scrollable>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="menu = false"
      >Cancel</v-btn
    >
    <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.menu.save(date)"
      >OK</v-btn
    >
  </v-date-picker>
```

```js
date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      disabledDates: {
        to: new Date(Date.now() - 8640000)
      },
      menu: false
```

I was trying with disabling the dates but it was disabling the whole datepicker, so I should I solve this problem any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to manual 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#month-pickers-allowed-months
this should work

```
methods: {
  allowedMonths: (val) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const cur = {
        month: date.getMonth() + 1,
        year: date.getFullYear(),
    };
    const prev = {
        month: cur.month === 1 ? 12 : cur.month - 1,
        year: cur.month === 1 ? cur.year - 1 : cur.year,
    };
    const valMonth = parseInt(val.split('-')[1], 10);
    const valYear = parseInt(val.split('-')[0], 10);
    return (valYear === cur.year && valMonth === cur.month) ||
        (valYear === prev.year && valMonth === prev.month);
  },
},
```

Comment: @Ronak07, this logic will fail if the current month is January. I have given a dynamic solution with the help of min and max in below answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code pen which used :min and :max props to set the date range

**The below logic will works for all the scenarios**

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/ZEbvJaR?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker :max="max" :min="min" v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      picker: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      min: "",
      max: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate(date) {
      var [date, month, year] = date.toLocaleDateString().split('/')
      return `${year}-${month}-${date}`;
    },
  },
  created() {

    this.min = this.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() - 1, 1));
    this.max = this.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0));
  }
})
```